# Do we count identity and inverse in "order of group"?

Tags: group-theory

This should be obvious, but this came up when I was reading Cauchy's theorem. If $G$ is a group, say $G = \{ g, g^{-1},e \}$. Is $|G| = 3$? The combinatorial argument in the theorem argues that the inverse is determined from the rest of the other elements and we appear to be excluding the identity too. Hence for $|X| = |G|^{p-1}$ where $X = \{ x_1\dots x_p =e\}$.

Comment: Yes. The order of a group is **by definition** the cardinality of the underlying set. If $G = \{e, a, a^{-1}\}$ with three distinct elements then $|G| = 3$.

Comment: @user296602 in https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_Theorem_(Group_Theory), the subgroup $X$ only has $p-1$ because the inverse is removed. This is my confusion

Comment: I don't understand your comment. $X$ has $n^{p - 1}$ elements, and there is no inverse that "is removed."

Comment: Also $X$ is a set. It isn't even considered as a group.

Comment: You should read the material from proofwiki more carefully, to avoid jumping to conclusions about what is said there. For example, the set $X$ is neither the number $|G|^{p-1}$ (as you said in the question) nor a subgroup (as you said in a comment).

Comment: Sorry let's say $X = \{ (a_1,a_2) :a_1a_2 = e\}$ Even counting $a_1 = a_2^{-1}$, aren't there two elements? @AndreasBlass that was a typo.

Comment: If you're still talking about the same $G=\{g,g^{-1},e\}$ as in the question, and if the $a_1$ and $a_2$ in your definition of $X$ are supposed to be members of $G$, then $X$ has three members: $(e,e)$, $(g,g^{-1})$, and $(g^{-1},g)$. That agrees with proofwiki, since $|G|=3$ and $p=2$ so $|G|^{p-1}=3$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thanks. that tripped me hard.